# Disable Email notifications

Tags: autodesk-data-management

We have an A360 team site and are uploading documents using the Data Management API.  Even though the option to Send email notifications is turned off in my user settings, I still get emailed when another team member uploads using the API.

I would like a way to disable notifications, even if the user has them turned on, since I am uploading a dozen text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only users themselves can opt to disable the notifications in their own accounts at this time.